# dynamic forms in django

Tags: django, django-forms

i've built my own dynamic form, kind of following james bennetts example.
using the following lines in forms.py

```
def make_question_form(request):
fields = { 'venue' : forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput()),
           'survey' : forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput())}
return type('Question_Form',(forms.BaseForm,), { 'base_fields': fields })
```

and the following in the view to build it (I know its not truely dynamic, i plan to add the dynamics next.

```
question_form = make_question_form(request)
question_form.base_fields['venue'] = this_venue.name
question_form.base_fields['survey'] = this_survey.name
return render_to_response("survey/questions.html", locals(), context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

but im not sure what to dowith it in the template and this is the bit that isn't really covered in the tutorials.

i've worked out that the following works

```
    {% for base_field in question_form.base_fields %}
        {{ base_field.type }}
    {% endfor %}
```

but i thought the point of building it as a form was to be able to do something like

```
question_form.as_p
```

and wrap it in my own form tags.

have i missed the point or should as_p work (it doesn't).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't instantiated the form in your view. `make_question_form` returns a new form *class* - normally when you use a form class in your view you do `form = MyFormClass()` or `form = MyFormClass(request.POST)`.

So you need to do `form = question_form()` before the `render_to_response`, then you'll be able to do `{{ form.as_p }}` in the template.

Comment: so would i be right in thinking the process is something like
    
    form = make_question_form()
    form.fields['blah'] = #get the fields, tag them on

then use {{ form.as_p }} in template?
    
I'll scurry off and try that.

Comment: gonna vote you right, cos i think i've worked out what you were telling me. will post some code later in case anyone finds it useful